# Redirect one html page to another using perl

Tags: html, perl, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a html form

```
<form id="branch" method="get" action="/x/local/.../perl_code.pl">

Branch Name : <input type="text" name="textBox">

<input type="submit" value="Generate">
</form>
```

and in perl_code.pl I have this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:standard);
my $value = uc(param('textBox'));
system "perl /x/local/.../perl_CODE21.pl $value";
#other system commands that work and output the index2.html
print redirect(-url=>'http://server.com:8080/project_name/index2.html');
```

What I eventually want to do is, get the input from the text box in `index1.html` retrieve the value in `perl_code` and do some `system` commands which print out `index2.html`and finally redirect it to `index2.html`. I have tried to manually inspect all other system commands and their output, they work. I am not able to retrieve the text value and pass it and also redirecting does not work. The browser redirects to `perl_code.pl` and gives a 404. I am currently running out of time. simple answers will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

This is a servlet program, so also suggest any modifications to web.xml if any.

Answer (score 3):

You can't redirect after an output to stdout. Either redirect or print, not both. Check that your `system` call doesn't do anything to stdout; or even better, redirect its stdout to something just in case (like `/dev/null`).

Comment: u say redirect(-url=>'http://server.com:8080/project_name/index2.html'); is enough? and also am i storing the value into the variable correctly? I am not sure about it

Comment: You might be storing the param correctly into the variable, but it would be safer if you surrounded it by quotes when invoking `system`, just in case it has special characters or spaces or something: `system "perl /x/local/.../perl_CODE21.pl \"$value\" > /dev/null"`. Also... if the other program is perl, why are you using `system` instead of just `use` it?

Comment: Also... "enough"? for what? If your `index2.html` is created by `perl_CODE21.pl`, then obviously you need it.

Comment: `system "perl /x/local/.../perl_CODE21.pl $value";
redirect(-url=>'http://server.com:8080/project_name/index2.html');` i used this and the html page redirects to ` perl_code.pl` and returns a 404. Also I am sorry I didnt mention this before, this actually is a servlet program running on tomcat. what should be the modifications in web.xml

Comment: Now I'm thoroughly confused. There's no way that command would redirect to `perl_code.pl`, especially since `"perl_code.pl"` does not actually appear anywhere in that line; unless the redirection is something that `perl_CODE21.pl` does. And any reason you didn't try what I suggested two comments up (about redirecting stdout to `/dev/null`)?

Comment: I tried `system "perl /x/local/.../perl_CODE21.pl $value > /dev/null 2>&1";` doesnt change anything. does the redirection have anything to do with the action in the html form?

Comment: i modified it as u said. and now it shows the perl code instead of executing. I searched online and found out that I need to uncomment stuff in web.xml (http://www.wellho.net/forum/Perl-Programming/Running-Perl-CGI-scripts-under-Apache-Tomcat.html). Also I was not able to find the two jars, I am not the root user and I was not able to find them. I cannot reach the tomcat server now.